# Display array contents as groups and sub-groups

Tags: php, html

I have an array of objects which looks similar to this:

```
$data = array(
    array('id' => 31, sort_position=>'1', 'code' => 'no_channels', 'title' => 'No of channels', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('9.5', '7.5', '5.5')),
    array('id' => 32, sort_position=>'2', 'code' => 'hdr10', 'title' => 'HDR 10', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HRD', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 36, sort_position=>'3', 'code' => 'dolby_vision', 'title' => 'Dolby Vision', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HRD', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 28, sort_position=>'4', 'code' => 'hlg', 'title' => 'HLG', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HRD', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 29, sort_position=>'5', 'code' => 'up_scaling', 'title' => 'Up scaling', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 33, sort_position=>'6', 'code' => 'release_year', 'title' => 'Release Year', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('2013', '2014', '2015')),
    array('id' => 34, sort_position=>'7', 'code' => '3d_audio', 'title' => '3D Audio', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 39, sort_position=>'8', 'code' => 'heos', 'title' => 'Heos', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HDMI', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 40, sort_position=>'9', 'code' => 'hdmi_inputs', 'title' => 'No. of HDMI Inputs', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HDMI', values=> array('2', '3', '4')),
    array('id' => 41, sort_position=>'10', 'code' => 'hdmi_outputs', 'title' => 'No. of HDMI Outputs', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('2', '3', '4'))
);
```

And I need to render this data like below image:

[image]

I could not find a way to render like this without messing `sort_position`. Has anyone have an idea how can I achieve desired structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following possible solution in php makes use of `json_encode()` followed by `json_decode()` to make it easier to access key-value pairs. An array of unique values is made for each of the required keys in the original data, and then the data is looped through with each of these arrays, while ensuring that there are no unnecessary duplications. The `sort_position` is automatically taken care of by the order in which the values are read, which implies prior sorting of the original data on the `sort_position`. The solution is:

```
$original_data = array(
    array('id' => 31, sort_position=>'1', 'code' => 'no_channels', 'title' => 'No of channels', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('9.5', '7.5', '5.5')),
    array('id' => 32, sort_position=>'2', 'code' => 'hdr10', 'title' => 'HDR 10', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HRD', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 36, sort_position=>'3', 'code' => 'dolby_vision', 'title' => 'Dolby Vision', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HRD', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 28, sort_position=>'4', 'code' => 'hlg', 'title' => 'HLG', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HRD', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 29, sort_position=>'5', 'code' => 'up_scaling', 'title' => 'Up scaling', 'group_title'=> 'Popular', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 33, sort_position=>'6', 'code' => 'release_year', 'title' => 'Release Year', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('2013', '2014', '2015')),
    array('id' => 34, sort_position=>'7', 'code' => '3d_audio', 'title' => '3D Audio', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 39, sort_position=>'8', 'code' => 'heos', 'title' => 'Heos', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HDMI', values=> array('yes', 'No')),
    array('id' => 40, sort_position=>'9', 'code' => 'hdmi_inputs', 'title' => 'No. of HDMI Inputs', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> 'HDMI', values=> array('2', '3', '4')),
    array('id' => 41, sort_position=>'10', 'code' => 'hdmi_outputs', 'title' => 'No. of HDMI Outputs', 'group_title'=> 'Audio', 'sub_group_title'=> NULL, values=> array('2', '3', '4'))
);

$json = json_encode($original_data);
$data = json_decode($json);

/* store unique values of the variables in aarrays */
$arr_group_titles = []; $arr_titles = [];$arr_sub_group_titles = [];$arr_codes = [];$arr_values = [];
foreach($data as $v){ 
if(!in_array($v->group_title, $arr_group_titles)){ $arr_group_titles[] = $v->group_title;}
if(!in_array($v->title, $arr_titles)){ $arr_titles[] = $v->title;}
if(!in_array($v->sub_group_title, $arr_sub_group_titles)){ $arr_sub_group_titles[] = $v->sub_group_title; }
if(!in_array($v->code, $arr_codes)){ $arr_code[] = $v->code;}
if(!in_array($v->value, $arr_values)){ $arr_values[] = $v->value;}}

/* Will use $arr_sub_group_taken to remove sub_group_title duplication: */
$arr_sub_group_taken = [];

/* Loop through the unique arrays with the data */
foreach($arr_group_titles as $group_title){
echo '<br/><strong>'.$group_title.' (parent group)</strong><br/>';
foreach($arr_titles as $title){
foreach($data as $v){ if($v->group_title == $group_title && $v->title == $title){ echo '--'.$title.'<br/>';
foreach($arr_sub_group_titles as $sub_group_title){
if(!in_array($sub_group_title,$arr_sub_group_taken) && !empty($sub_group_title) && $v->group_title == $group_title && $v->title == $title && $v->sub_group_title == $sub_group_title ){
echo '&emsp;'.$sub_group_title.' (sub group)<br/>'; $arr_sub_group_taken[] = $sub_group_title;}
if($v->sub_group_title == $sub_group_title){
 foreach($v->values as $u){ echo '&emsp;&emsp;'.$u.'<br/>'; }
}}}}}}
```

The output is:

```
 /*
   Popular (parent group)
    --No of channels
      9.5
      7.5
      5.5
    --HDR 10
     HRD (sub group)
      yes
      No
    --Dolby Vision
      yes
      No
    --HLG
      yes
      No
    --Up scaling
      yes
      No

    Audio (parent group)
    --Release Year
      2013
      2014
      2015
    --3D Audio
      yes
      No
    --Heos
     HDMI (sub group)
      yes
      No
    --No. of HDMI Inputs
      2
      3
      4
    --No. of HDMI Outputs
      2
      3
      4 */
```

Comment: Thank you Johan B. for the answer. I helped me to find a workaround.